# In Argo workflow, how to add resource manifest as json instead of string

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

In [Argo Workflow](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#resourcetemplate), I am unable to create resources with manifest in json format. Only string is allowed and that string content should be in yaml format. This is weird to have a json and one parameter is passed as string in a yaml format.

Is there a better way to do this ?

```
## This doesn't work. spec > template > resource > manifest is expected as string

{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "delightful-tiger"
  },
  "spec": {
    "entrypoint": "test-config-create",
    "templates": [
      {
        "name": "test-config-create",
        "resource": {
          "action": "create",
          "manifest": {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
              "parameters.json": "{}"
            },
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
              "name": "sairam_config"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
# this works.
{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "delightful-tiger"
  },
  "spec": {
    "entrypoint": "test-config-create",
    "templates": [
      {
        "name": "test-config-create",
        "resource": {
          "action": "create",
          "manifest": "apiVersion: v1\nkind: ConfigMap\nmetadata:\n  name: ...."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```